# ASP.NET Gridview to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have a page with `Gridview` and when button clicked I should export data from `Gridview` to `.xls` file. I have tried it in many ways. This is my code:

```
protected void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        //Response.Buffer = true;
        //Response.ClearHeaders();
        //Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        //Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposion","attachment; filename=Clients.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(swriter);
        grid.RenderControl(hwriter);
        Response.Write(swriter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

The problem is when I click the button it is exporting `aspx` file. I have tried all answers in **Stackoverflow** and from other sources as well. However, I am not being able to correct it. I need exact reason why it is so and some possible solutions.(I tried `Content-type` as `"application/excel"`, `"application/vn"`, `"application/vn-excel"` as well.)

Comment: Full Code here : https://www.codeproject.com/tips/477436/export-gridview-data-to-excel-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just follow following code, it is working fine..

> ```
> protected void cmdExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     Response.Clear();
>     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=SupplierList.xls");
>     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
>     System.IO.StringWriter WriteItem = new System.IO.StringWriter();
>     System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlText = new HtmlTextWriter(WriteItem);
>     GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
>     DataTable dtSupplier = (DataTable)ViewState["dtSupplier"];
>     GridView1.DataSource = dtSupplier;
>     GridView1.DataBind();
>     GridView1.RenderControl(htmlText);
>     Response.Write(WriteItem.ToString());
>     Response.End();
> }
> ```

Hope this will help you.
thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been searching it for 2 days. Why my code is not working??? Do not you know about it???